# What is the etymology of the word blueprint? Why is it blue?

Tags: etymology

What is the etymology of the word *blueprint*? Is this a fairly recent word? I'm wondering why the word "blue" is there.

Comment: Have you looked up the word? A [blueprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blueprint) is literally printed in blue colour… I can’t see what there is to explain.

Comment: Just for info, to “blueprint” an engine means to make every part to the closest tolerances and this usually improves the performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1857!  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/20610#eid17561306) **blueprint**

- > - Originally: a photographic print composed of white lines on a blue    background, used chiefly in copying plans, machine drawings, etc.;
  >     (also) a blue-toned photograph. In later use also (more generally):
  >     any design or technical drawing. Also attributive. Cf. blue paper.

As in:

> - 1857   Photogr. Notes    The toning of this **blue print** with a    uranium or copper bath holds out therefore the prospect of a good
>     result.

[Etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/word/blueprint) give a slightly different date of use:

**blueprint** (n.)

also blue-print, 1882, from blue (adj.1) + print (n.). The process uses blue on white, or white on blue. Figurative sense of "detailed plan" is attested from 1926. As a verb by 1939.

I will go with the OED: white lines on **blue** paper for plans and machine drawings.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen real "blueprints" made.  The original (which must be on thin paper such a velum) is placed over a sheet of photo-sensitive paper, then the pair is exposed to a strong light.  The photo-sensitive paper is then dipped into a developing bath, and the areas struck by light (which passed through the thin paper but not the ink-darkened areas) turn blue.  It is a "negative" of sorts.

(Many people are more familiar with the "positive" blue-on-white version of a blueprint, but this was achieved by going through the process twice, similar to developing a photo "negative" then making a "print" of it.)

As stated elsewhere, this technology goes back about 150 years, though the chemical specifics have changed, and the process largely passed out of use about 40 years ago as xerographic copies became more practical.

The metaphorical meaning of "blueprint", as a plan or scheme for something, almost certainly ties back to the use of physical blueprints to contain the plans for building construction -- this was the most common use of blueprints during their heyday (though they were also used to represent plans for electrical circuits and even, occasionally, computer flowcharts).

Comment: (Curious as to why this was down-voted.)